# How can I get this symbol without using bbold?

Tags: symbols

[image]

A solution I saw somewhere suggested to use

```
\usepackage{bbold}
$\mathbb{1}$
```

which works well and I get what I want. However, now other symbols used to represent real numbers, natural numbers, etc look ugly.

[image: ugly symbols]

I'd like them to look (without using bbold)

[image: not ugly symbols]

I'd like to only use that package to achieve that strange double one. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about `dsfont`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\mathds{1}$ and $\mathbb{B}$ or $\mathds{B}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The modern toolchain, with `unicode-math`, lets you select any TrueType or OpenType font for blackboard bold, or any subset of blackboard bold.  For example,

```
\setmathfont[Scale = MatchUppercase, range=\Bbbone]{XITS Math}
```

changes only that one symbol, while

```
\setmathfont[Scale = MatchUppercase, range=bb]{STIX Two Math}
```

changes the entire blackboard bold alphabet.

Answer (score 5):

You can just borrow the glyph from the `bbold` font.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\bbone}{\text{\usefont{U}{bbold}{m}{n}1}}
\MakeRobust{\bbone}

\begin{document}

$\bbone\in\mathbb{R}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The “robustness” is needed for uses in moving arguments (sectional titles or captions).

Comment: I am smiling for your answer because I remember that you did not like the number one of `dsfont` in my book. :-).+1 for all answers and the question.